# Separation of data and objects with lists in the data class C#

Tags: c#, architecture

I've got small C# app with a **Data Layer** class that calls directly to the database, and a **Business Layer** that defines objects that the system uses.

The problem is that I have a **Data Layer** data class referencing the **Business Layer** to return lists of objects, so I can't also reference the data class from the business class to populate objects.

So, if I have an "assignment" object in my **Business Layer**, and I populate it with a Data Table returned from the **Data Layer** (which in turn gets the data from a SQL Server Databases), then **Business Layer** must reference **Data Layer**

However, if I want to return **List**  from the **Data Layer** that's calling a proc from SQL to return assignments, I have to reference the **Business Layer** so it knows what type to return (what an "Assignment is")

What's the best practice for returning data to a business object both as a single record or as a list? Should I send the data from the **Data Layer** to the **Business Layer** to load into a list?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I don't usually put services inside the business layer. To maintain separation I make a service layer that depends on the data layer and business layer. It hydrates the business objects and knows how to store them in the data layer.

Comment: I guess I see where you are getting concerned. To return a typed list or a single typed object you DB layer must know about the types. So to keep the DB layer ignorant of the BL layer can I send it up untyped? No!. The best is to let the DB layer know about your object classes and let it handle all is need to "serialize/deserialize" it from/to records.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your diagram two things came to my mind. Certainly not as the or a *"solution"* but as questions and suggestions.

1) The three layers as such make good sense but they are quite abstract; at least until the missing **"presentation layer"** is added (on the left hand.)

Sounds too practical/involved/..? But it will bring flesh and life to the other layers, especially when you..

2) Write down **use cases**. That is: **Write** them down and make it **enough**, say 5-10 minimum. Also make sure each entity in your architecture get used/mentioned a least 5 times as well in the use cases.

Tedious? And nesessary to make sure each item is well understood and will work together with the others; and that the architeture will handle the growth of the 50, 500 or what not cases it will eventually have to cover.